# Facebook comment into my blog

Tags: plugins, facebook

I want that whenever I post my blog in facebook, anyone who comment in FB will automatically reflect those comments in my blog.
Is this possible? how?
My WP version is 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-comments-for-wordpress/

Should be working for what you want to do.